# Why can undefined be implicitly returned without an error?

Tags: typescript, option-type

The following example may return a non-number type (`undefined`)

```js
function foo(x: number): number
{
    if (x != 5) { return x+2; }
    
    // undefined returned here
}

var arg = process.argv[2];
console.log(foo(Number(arg)))
```

How come I get no type-check error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get no compile time error because you have not enabled the `noImplicitReturns` rule.

Go into your `tsconfig.json` and add the rule under `compilerOptions`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* ... */
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
  },
}
```

The following error will be emitted now:

```
function foo(x: number): number {
//                       ^^^^^^ Error: Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'
    if (x != 5) { return x+2; }
    
    // undefined returned here
}
```

The error message might differ depending on how you set `strictNullChecks` (*"Not all code paths return a value"*). I would recommend setting `strictNullChecks` to `true` if that is not already the case.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUAPAXIsIC2ARgKYBOAlDnkWYgN4CwAUAPQuIedfc8cB6AwYgCipUnFI4AYuGjwkAGwCGEANYBnRMTAATGGADmiUsSghSSdVCVRi+bVERLdx0+aRQAngAdiiHXDEmmBwjvoQCiA6fgDk4NHA+sQ6McxcMMCImIgAhAC8iACs5PSuZhaIGADUAEwA3IgAvmmcLRxsiPHEiWDJZe59ABZkxMzNTMwAbkqkTqRGBd7iEEHqAHQzBpMA2jUAunXMEAjqcArEawpwBmgo6AByBCSkaJvk70A)